# No records in database after HTTP Post Request in Java

Tags: java, php, http

Im trying to do a HTTP Post request to my webpage from my Bukkit Minecraft plugin...

Now here's the code im using for the java side:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://[::1]/reporter/getreport.php");

    String username = this.getConfig().getString("username");
    String password = this.getConfig().getString("password");

    String query = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
    query += "&";
    query += "password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
    query += "&";
    query += "sender=" + URLEncoder.encode(sender.getName(), "UTF-8"); 
    query += "&";
    query += "target=" + URLEncoder.encode(target.getName(), "UTF-8");
    query += "&";
    query += "reason=" + URLEncoder.encode(reason, "UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(query.getBytes().length));
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(query);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    connection.disconnect();

    sender.sendMessage("Reported!");

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now im trying to do this using XAMPP, where my local database and pages are stored, which is connected to using localhost.

Here is the PHP code I am using to connect to:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/db.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sender = $_POST['sender'];
$target = $_POST['target'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];

try {
    $SQL = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO reports (username, password, sender, target, reason, time) VALUES (:username, :password, :sender, :target, :reason, :time)');
    $SQL->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $SQL->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $SQL->bindParam(':sender', $sender);
    $SQL->bindParam(':target', $target);
    $SQL->bindParam(':reason', $reason);
    $SQL->bindParam(':time', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    $SQL->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {

}

?>
```

Can anyone spot the problem? It's been bugging me for a few days now and I can't find a solution anywhere...

EDIT:: I don't want to be using Apache's HttpClient stuff...

Thanks in advance!

~ Ryan

Comment: Can you verify that all parameters reach PHP correctly?

Comment: How could i verify that?

Comment: print them to your server log

Comment: I checked if the page was being opened and it gave me a status code of 200 -> Okay

Comment: yes, but did `$username` and friends contain proper data? Also, don't just ignore the PDOException. At least log it.

Comment: Yeah it contained strings